# PHP: When does the temporary uploaded files get deleted?

Tags: php, file-upload

I am running WAMP server. On file upload using PHP I see

`$_FILES[tmp_name] => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\phpD382.tmp' (length=23)`

I go to that folder and it's empty. I made sure my 'show hidden files' is on from my 'folders option' but I don't see it. Where is it exactly?

Besides when does it get deleted? If I don't move that file? For an instance if I'm uploading a file and the file uploaded halfway and I decided to close that browser what happens to the file? When does the server know to delete that temp file?

Comment: as soon as the script finishes. "The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed. " http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: @Dagon What happens if the script gets interrupted, like if I close the browser or press the back button?

Comment: in both cases the file or what ever part of the file was uploaded will be deleted

Comment: @Dagon unless `ignore_user_abort` has been set in the API or has been called.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder i would have thought even in that case closing the browser would stop the file being sent. tested it -yup file upload stops server side cant control that.

Comment: @Dagon Point taken. I was assuming the file was already uploaded when the user pushed the back button, but this probably won't always be the case.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As soon as your PHP script finishes executing and re-saving to the defined location

### Example using straight PHP, no framework

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

```
$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: on some WAMP installations your `$uploaddir` might be something like `C:/wamp/www/uploads/` and the `$_FILES` array might be using `file`, not `userfile`

Comment: Considering the file isn't re-saved in a defined location (ex: read an excel file, get the data -> insert to db, toss the file), does php destroy the tmp file anyway at the end of the script?

Comment: Nvm found it:

The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed.

Comment: @gorelative What happens if I rename the file within the tmp dir? Does it too get deleted after the script execution finished ?

Answer (score 11):

If you do not do anything with them they will be deleted right after the script is finished.

Comment: How to know when script is finished because I want to apply same behavior on another folder?

Comment: This is a late reply. But it could help others. You could try registering a callback function with the register_shutdown_function. This function gets invoked when a script ends. A script could also end when there is a fatal error. This could also be caught inside the function and steps taken as needed.

Comment: Do you have a source for your statement? And what happens when the script gets interrupted with a fatal error?
Found this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php
> The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed.

Answer (score 7):

If deleting file is not desired, i found that PHP wont delete file after execution if you "move" it to same location.

```
move_uploaded_file($temporaryFile, $temporaryFile);
```