# Is it secure to dispatch a job to process a temporary file?

Tags: php, laravel

Since temporary files are automatically deleted after the current script is finished [(#50778308)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131226/php-when-does-the-temporary-uploaded-files-get-deleted), If I dispatch a **Laravel Job** to process an uploaded file, which is simply temporary file, is there a risk that the file won't be found?

Comment: If you need to process this file, store it on your storage folder, then delete it on your job after processing it.

Comment: Exactly @EliasSoares and you can also safely resize, reformat or watermark it. Don't rely on the queue for this type of job. I have actually unqueued uploading files. Even to S3. The processing, once uploaded, goes so fast, there is no need for a queue.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Job will not be able to access the temporary uploaded file. Jobs are processed by a separate worker process after the request has already finished, which means temp files have already been removed.

As Elias said, the solution is to [save the file](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#storing-files) during the request, and then the job can delete the file when it's done processing.

The exception is when you use the `sync` queue driver, which processes jobs immediately when they're dispatched. In this case the job is run *during* the request, so the job would be able to access the temporary uploaded file.